# Integrating with SciPy when variables of a function are arrays

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numerical-integration

I am a Python newbie trying to learn scientific computing, hence some help would be appreciated with this matter. What I am trying to do is to integrate a function when 4 variables take values from given arrays. It works well when only 1 variable is represented by an array, but doesn't work for 4 variables. 
For example, this works:

```
    import scipy.integrate as integrate
    from numpy import *

    values1 = [3.333, 6.667, 10, 13.333, 16.667, 20] #these are test1 values
    test2 = -2.333 
    test3 = 4.333
    test4 = 0.4918
    test5 = -12.005

    f = lambda u : (u**(test1-1))*((1-u)**test3-test1-1)*((1-u*test4)**-test2)*exp(u*test5)
    I=[]

    for test1 in values1:
    result, err = integrate.quad(f,0,1)
    I.append(result)

    print(I)
```

What I am trying to do, but doesn't work:

```
    import scipy.integrate as integrate
    from numpy import *

    values1 = [3.333, 6.667, 10, 13.333, 16.667, 20] #these are test1 values
    values2 = [-2.333, -5.667, -9, -12.333, -15.667, -19] #these are test2 values 
    values3 = [4.333, 7.667, 11, 14.333, 17.667, 21] #these are test3 values
    test4 = 0.4918 #this is constant
    values5 = [-12.005, -12.063, -12.121, -12.178, -12.235, -12.293] #these are test5 values

    f = lambda u : (u**(test1-1))*((1-u)**test3-test1-1)*((1-u*test4)**-test2)*exp(u*test5)
    I=[]

    for test1, test2, test3, test5 in values1, values2, values3, values5:
    result, err = integrate.quad(f,0,1)
    I.append(result)

    print(I)
```

I get **ValueError: too many values to unpack** referring to for loop. I can imagine that the loop has to be expanded to accommodate all arrays, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

With the `for .. in ..` loop you can not iterate through multiple lists at once, like you did in your example code.
You can use the function `zip(...)` which returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each list, like this:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from numpy import *

values1 = [3.333, 6.667, 10, 13.333, 16.667, 20] #these are test1 values
values2 = [-2.333, -5.667, -9, -12.333, -15.667, -19] #these are test2 values 
values3 = [4.333, 7.667, 11, 14.333, 17.667, 21] #these are test3 values
test4 = 0.4918 #this is constant
values5 = [-12.005, -12.063, -12.121, -12.178, -12.235, -12.293] #these are test5 values

f = lambda u : (u**(test1-1))*((1-u)**test3-test1-1)*((1-u*test4)**-test2)*exp(u*test5)
I=[]

for test1, test2, test3, test5 in zip(values1, values2, values3, values5):  # Change this line
    result, err = integrate.quad(f,0,1)
    I.append(result)

print(I)
```